# Batch removing X number of lines from file from Nth line

Tags: batch-file, line, findstr

I am trying to remove a tag from a set of html files and I can't seem to find the right commands to do the job.

I am able to find the line number of the tag; the tag is a total of 10 lines that need to be deleted. Once I find this line, how do I got and delete said line & next 10 lines?

Here's what I have (a first for loop to collect files, a second for loop that collects all line numbers.) thank you.

```
::start by creating a list of html files
set i=0
for /r %%G in (*.html) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set array[!i!]=%%G
)
set n=%i%

::second nested loop collects all lines for bottom secion to be deleted.
set j = 0
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
     for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n /c:"u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey 80" !array[%%i]!') do (
         set var=%%a
         set /A j+=1
         set array[!j!]=!var:~0,3!
     )
)
set m=%j%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory & destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

for /r "%sourcedir%" %%G in (*.html) do (
 SET "linecount="
 FOR /f "delims=:" %%e IN ('findstr /n /c:"u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey 80" "%%G"') DO SET /a linecount=%%e
 IF DEFINED linecount (
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%%G") DO (
   SET /a linecount-=1
   IF !linecount! gtr 0 ECHO %%b
   IF !linecount! lss -10 ECHO %%b
  )
 )>"%destdir%\tempfile"& MOVE /y "%destdir%\tempfile" "%%G" >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Start a recursive directory list of the target files from `sourcedir`.

Initialise `linecount` to *nothing* and use `findstr` to locate the target string. `%%e` will be set to the number of the line found, `set` this into `linecount`.

If the string was found, `linecount` will now contain a value, so read each line and count down. If `linecount` is between 0 and -10, we don't `echo` the line to the output file.

I originally put all the generated files in the one directory. Yours to change at will.

Revised to generate a temporary file (quite *where* would be irrelevant) and then move that file over the original.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! Albeit I still have one more newbie problem. I want to overwrite the exact file, and the above command will place all the files only in the same folder (many of the html files are in sub folders.)

I attempted to solve this by setting the output to just be %%G after the >, but this does not work.

it left me with a "The system cannot find the file" error

Comment: It would seem that the temporary file does not exist. Does it exist? Can you create a new file in the directory `%%~dpG`? You could try `echo`ing the `move` command (simply add the keyword `echo` after the `&` on that line and remove the `>nul`) Does the `move` command `echo`ed reveal anything?

Comment: the new update helped. I still feel confused during testing as it will randomly stop finding the line needed and I don't know why. but for the most part it does work. This is confusing as the behavior seems to change with almost no changes.

But this does work and it completes my question, thank you.